# How to use like function in a set of data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

is there a way i can use like function in a set of data?
i tried 
select * from table1 where column1 like ('%1%','%2%','%3%','%4%');
but it didn't work.

my scenario is having 2 select statements such as select * from class1 where firstname in (select name from class2 where firstname = 'greg');

but instead of having class1.firstname = class2.firstname i wanted it to be class1.firstname like concat('%',class2.firstname,'%');

Comment: Have you considered normalizing your database?

Comment: i guess i'll use the OR function since its my only option.

Answer (score 1):

You could "OR" them:

```
... WHERE (column1 like '%1%') OR (column1 like '%2%') OR ...
```

Answer (score 0):

like takes one argument

```
select * 
from table1 
where column1 like ('%1%');
```

if you want to check for many then use `OR` or `UNION` operators

```
select * 
from table1 
where column1 like ('%1%')
or column1 like ('%2%');
```

Comment: Note that UNION will return a row with string "12" twice - once for "%1%" and once for "%2%".

Comment: No `UNION` remove duplicate rows, that's the case when you use `UNION ALL` as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use the `IN` function when you have a list of strings to compare to. But here you need a combination of `LIKE` and `IN`, and as far as I know there is no function in SQL that does this, so you'll need to use the `OR` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execute.html) to build the dynamic sql, but you must beware of safety and performance issues that may arise.

Another options is using `regex`

Comment: i guess i wont take the risk. tnx